# FFMPEG: m4a to mp3 conversion using multiple cores

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, conversion, mp3

I use the following command to convert m4a format to mp3

```
ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -acodec libmp3lame audio.mp3
```

I've 32 x86 cores, however libmp3lame processes in a single thread. I know libmp3lame does not support multithreading, thus I'm open to other alternates that can be executed in ubuntu CLI.

If audio.m4a is 2hours long video, that usually takes > 3minutes and speed appears to be 45x to 50x.

My primary goal is to convert multiple youtube videos in mp3 format within seconds.

Update 1:

Since I'm using 32 cores CPU, when there's only one video conversion it utilizes just one core. So in that cases how to use multiple cores, to get output faster. I want to achieve the maximum from the CPU. Also if FFmpeg is not the answer, is there any other way.

Comment: Couldn't you just start multiple ffmpeg processes in parallel?

Comment: @slhck no, libmp3lame does not support multiple threads :(

Comment: You mean, even when you start, say, 20 different ffmpeg processes, only one core is used?

Comment: @slhck no dear, I'm saying one process one core

Comment: So what I'm suggesting is to start 20 processes. Does that not work?

Comment: @slhck Do you mean single audio conversion using multiple cores? How do we do it?

Comment: You can't.  Splitting an audio conversion into multiple cores would require multiple input streams, and then the ability to splice them together when done -- which would make audible clicks.  You can script this, but you won't like the output.

Answer (score 5):

[GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

Here is an example of how you could use *GNU Parallel* (assuming you already have a directory with all your `*.m4a` files named `videos`) using your original commands:

```
find /path/to/videos -name "*.m4a" | parallel 'ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame {.}.mp3'
```

Two things to explain:

**1**: The output of the `find` command (i.e. the list of `.m4a` files to convert) will be piped into the `parallel` command, which will in turn (by default) *execute as many jobs as there are cores*. In essence it is splitting the output from the `find` command, and distributing it across the different jobs to *work on*.

**2**: Per the [GNU Parallel Tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#The-7-predefined-replacement-strings), `{}` is where your arguments will go, `{.}` will substitute in your arguments and remove the terminal extension (in this case the `.m4a`), and your output will be the original file name but with `.mp3` extension.

**NOTE**: This example will write all your converted files to where your original files are. If this is an issue, then merely pass a directory to store the converted files in the argument string containing the `ffmpeg` command:

```
find /path/to/videos -name "*.m4a" | parallel 'ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame /path/to/converted/vids/{.}.mp3'
```

Comment: (1) So, if (as stated) it takes the OP three minutes to process a file, with your technique he will be able to process 32 files in three minutes.  That may be the best he can get, but that's not what he's looking for — he's looking for a way to process *one* file in under ten seconds.  (2) Please don't use `ls` to generate filenames for another process to use (or advise people to do so).

Answer (score 2):

Since the encoder is single-threaded only, in order to make the encoding the most efficient on a multi-core system, all you can do is launch several processes in parallel.

For example, if you're in a shell:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c:a libmp3lame output1.mp3 &
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c:a libmp3lame output2.mp3 &
…
```

The `&` puts the command [into the background](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html). The commands will be run in parallel and the load should be distributed among your CPU cores.

Comment: Yes dear, I know. What I want is make the single process happen in multithread.

Comment: I've updated my question, please check. Thank you

Comment: You can't magically make a single-threaded process execute in multiple threads. There is a standalone multithread version of LAME available, but I cannot guarantee that it works well: https://github.com/dheller1/lame_pthreads

Comment: have a look at this website onlinevideoconverter.com/es

it does conversions almost instantly.

Answer (score 2):

There are multi-threaded implementations of lame mp3 encoder on the internet.
I could track one here

`https://github.com/dheller1/lame_pthreads`

If you have large storage space, you could use ffmpeg to convert all m4a files into wav files and then point lame_pthreads to that folder.

Comment: From the description: *Use multithreading to encode several files in parallel, but only use
   a single thread for each file.* So it encodes *multiple* files in parallel. In other words: It will not speed up encoding a single (big) file. Just to make this clear.